# Python Speed Up Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am creating a small python script to find pages of sites, forums etc through a username, you can easily understand it. I'm going to use request, however it is really very slow between one search and another. Do you have any solutions to recommend? Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from printy import printy, inputy

username = inputy("[?] Username: ", "b")



fivehundredpx = requests.get('https://www.500px.com/'+ username)

if fivehundredpx.status_code == 200:
    printy('500px Found: https://www.500px.com/'+ username, "n")
elif fivehundredpx.status_code == 404:
    printy('500px Not Found', "r")



sevencups = requests.get('https://www.7cups.com/@'+ username)

if sevencups.status_code == 200:
    printy('7Cups Found: https://www.7cups.com/@'+ username, "n")
elif sevencups.status_code == 404:
    printy('7Cups Not Found', "r")
```

Comment: This would probably fit better on [se.cr](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not really control the speed of the requests processing by server, neither you can control your network latency, however you might be able to increase effective RPS using **multi-threading** with desired concurrency level.

Here is a code snippet that shows how you can achieve having multiple requests in-flight to increase overall processing speed. Hopefully [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) is not really a problem when it comes down to IO and you can really have an order of magnitude of performance improvements.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def parse_skeleton(parse_fn, start=1, end=1_000_000, concurrency=10):

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=concurrency, thread_name_prefix='parser') as executor:

        for id in range(start, end):
            executor.submit(parse_fn, id)
```